# LINQ Distinct()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on getting the results of this sql query in LINQ

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Type)
FROM  Product
WHERE categoryID = @catID
```

**this is my repository query:**

```
public IQueryable<ProdInfo> GetProdInfo()
        {

            var data = from u in db.Prod
                       select new ProdInfo
                       {
                           PID = u.PID,
                           CatID = u.CatID,                           
                           LastChanged = u.LastChanged,
                           ChangedBy = u.ChangedBy,                               
                           Type = u.Type,
                       };

            return data;
        }
```

**filter:**

```
public static IQueryable<ProdInfo> GetDistinctProdType(this IQueryable<ProdInfo> qry,int CatID)
            {
                return from p in qry
                       where p.CatID.Equals(CatID)
                       select p;
            }
```

I need the filter to return the distinct prod type? How can i do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
public static IQueryable<ProdType> GetDistinctProdType(
    this IQueryable<ProdInfo> query,
    int categoryId)
{
    return (from p in query
            where p.CatID == categoryId
            select p.Type).Distinct();
}
```

Note that I've changed the return type - it should match whatever the type of `ProdInfo.Type` is.

You may find it more readable to use the extension methods for the whole query if the query expression itself is reasonably simple:

```
public static IQueryable<ProdType> GetDistinctProdType(
    this IQueryable<ProdInfo> query,
    int categoryId)
{
    return query.Where(p => p.CatID == categoryId)
                .Select(p => p.Type)
                .Distinct();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
return (from p in qry
       where p.CatId.Equals(CatID)
       select p.Type).Distinct();
```

This matches what your provided SQL Query should be doing.