# Linq distinct equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How do you use LINQ (C#) to select the value in a particular column for a particular row in a datatable. The equivalent SQL would be:

select Distinct page_no from pagetable;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google it first please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144409/linq-distinct

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = YourContext.pagetable.Select(x => x.page_no).Distinct()
```

Comment: If it's really a `DataTable` it is Linq-To-DataSet: `var result = pagetable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int>("page_no")).Distinct()`

Comment: thanks.  it help me a lot. i'm a beginner for C#. but anyway thank again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = source.Select(x => x.Property).Distinct();
```

or for `DataTable`:

```
var items = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("columnName")).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) and [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx):

```
var distinctThings = things.Select(i => i.Property).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [MoreLINQ project](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), which adds some of the methods that should have been a part of LINQ to Objects in the first place.